# Why is the Knockout 'with' binding necessary when using an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

This question is based of the code from step 2 of the Knockout online tutorial here: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail

Using this jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PKDdG/

Lines 10 through 12 currently use the `with` Knockout binding:

```
<table class="mails" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData">
    <thead><tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: mails">
```

The tutorial explains:

> The with binding creates a binding context that will be used when binding any elements inside it. In this example, everything inside the  will be bound to chosenFolderData, so it's not necessary to use chosenFolderData. as a prefix before mails.

I tried replacing lines 10 through 12 with the following, based off testing the quote above:

```
<table class="mails">
    <thead><tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: chosenFolderData().mails">
```

And I am getting an `Cannot read property 'Inbox' of undefined` error in the console.

In the tutorial, why is the `with` binding necessary for the code to work? I understand it is changing the binding concept, but why cannot I manually select the binding context with the `chosenFolderData.` prefix?

Comment: [I found this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762396/knockoutout-js-why-are-these-values-not-binding-correctly?rq=1), but using the prefix seems to work. Why does it not work in this case? I suspect including the `with` might force the code to wait for the Ajax request to return or something, but I'm still unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens with the `with` binding is that if the property you are binding with the `with` is null or undefined, it will skip the bindings inside (it actually won't render those elements). When you remove the `with` it tries to bind `chosenFolderData` when it's undefined and so all the inner property bindings fail. Once it hits an error, knockout quits trying to bind the rest of your model.

You could achieve the same result using an `if` binding:

```
<table class="mails" data-bind="if: chosenFolderData">
    <thead><tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: chosenFolderData().mails">
```

As the `if` binding will give you a similar result. See http://jsfiddle.net/PKDdG/166/

The `with` is a convenience to save you having to keep putting in long chains of property access.

This is mentioned in the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html), but it's perhaps not as clear and obvious at it ought to be:

> The with binding will dynamically add or remove descendant elements depending on whether the associated value is null/undefined or not